# iphone camera application

Tags: iphone, image-processing, medical

while in graduate school for biomedical eng I developed a device we called a "vein finder".  It was a simple device that was good enough for our eng school to patent.

I think it would be very very easy to use the iphone camera to develop an iphone app whereby MD's/ nurses/EMT's could use the app to easily identify peripherial veins that are not visible to the naked eye.  This would be invaluable in starting IV's and giving bedside medications.  The vein finder was esp helpful for patients in shock who had poor venous filling and therefore didn't have veins that "popped into view" with a tourniquet.

It would require using the iphone light at specific wavelengths... anybody have any idea if that is possible?

Comment: This is really an image-processing question rather than a programming question - should probably be migrated to http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: The flash is an LED. It is a physical impossibility to modify the wavelength of light from an LED.

Comment: I hope you don't plan to sell it on your own, because medical software and hardware has to pass a huge number of certifications before one can use it to take medical decision based on it. Be prepared for a lot of tests and paperwork. In fact, I think Apple would have to get the iphone camera approved in some ways for this to work. An I doubt they will put a lot of energy into it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have any control over the flash light that illuminates images. You can only turn it on and off. I also doubt you would be able to get the specific wavelengths you need.

My suggestion would be to look into building a peripheral light device which plugs in to the headphone jack for power and has the necessary functions for emitting light at different wavelengths. That way, you would be able to get the exact result you require.

You may also need to look into the camera itself, as it may not have the ability to capture the light at the wavelengths you may require. Hope that Helps!

Comment: oh dear... I see fame and fortune rapidly disipating.  I've already built the "peripheral light device.  The neat thing would be folks needing only their iphone and not lugging around extra equipment. BTW... I know the camera will do it as I've experimented with my light source and the iphone camera. I'm going to be really pissed if I sent this app on Itunes tomorrow!  :)

Comment: I don't think any person will steal your idea, we're here to help! As I don't know much about your process, I can't really offer any other solutions. Maybe you could try something with strobing the flash light at different rates? Or maybe you could create some image filters that could highlight certain ROI's based on the lighting of the flash? Just guessing here...

Comment: the quick replies much appreciated!  The critical parts of the equation would be... open camera + control of light at specific wavelengths + all you need is your iphone = lotta money

Comment: Yeah, if you definitely need control of light at specific wavelengths, then you'll need a device to attach to the phone. You may want to try contacting Apple about this, and see if they have any plans to allow more fine-tuned control of the light. Also, getting everything ready and then waiting for them to offer more control in a future iOS version may be a good idea. That way, you can follow the beta releases and start testing immediately if such controls are ever offered!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean overlaying veins over the picture on the camera?  It would be easy if the veins are always in the same place... What would your imagined procedure be for using this app?

EDIT: You can not manipulate the iPhone light for different frequencies; you can only turn it on and off.  You would need to get a separate external light for that.

Comment: If veins were always in the same place you wouldn't really need to find them.

Comment: the camera would need to stay open ... unnecessay to take photos.

Comment: the camera would need to stay open ... unnecessay to take photos.  Point the iphone at a hand, see onscreen, and have the iphone light continously on at SPECIFIC WAVELENGHTS ...

Answer (score 0):

To work around the fact that you can't set the wavelength of the built in light, you should use an external light along with the iOS device.

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for massive necro!

The LED light of the iPhone is not the problem - most white light sources contain IR or near-IR (in fact they are made up from the entire visible spectrum). Daylight works very well too.

The problem is the receiver. Most camera lenses, including smartphones, have an IR filter - thus cutting out the useful part of the spectrum. All we need is a digital camera with IR filter removed, that has a viewfinder (where you'll see the veins).